# Mapping polylines with Z dimension ("ribbon plot") in ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-online, 3d-map

I have a polyline feature class with an attribute (“value”) that I would like to map in ArcGIS online. Specifically, I would like to display the lines as a curtain or ribbon where the height above ground level is set proportionally based on “value”. In Google Earth, using KML, it is pretty easy to generate a map along these lines:

[image]

How can I generate a similar display in ArcGIS online? Ideally, I would like this display to appear in an interactive 3D view within ArcGIS Online.